# "The language of the question/answer"

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Are these sentences correct?

> - I have changed the language of the question, so that you may understand easily.
> - I have changed the language of the answer, so that you may understand easily.

Is this use of the word *language* correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly makes sense, but *language* risks being understood as **another** language, such as French or German . If you want to avoid that risk, you can say *wording* instead.